# Strange behaviour of eager take

Tags: raku

Naturally lazy

```
D:\>6e "my @bar = 'a', 'b', 'c'; sub foo( @b ) { my $bar = 0; gather loop { print "*"; take ($bar, @b[$bar]); $bar++; last if $bar > 2; } }; .print for foo( @bar )"
*(0 a)*(1 b)*(2 c)
```

So far, so expected. Now, let's be eager.

```
D:\>6e "my @bar = 'a', 'b', 'c'; sub foo( @b ) { my $bar = 0; eager gather loop { print "*"; take ($bar, @b[$bar]); $bar++; last if $bar > 2; } }; .print for foo( @bar )"
***(3 a)(3 b)(3 c)
```

Why on earth are the numeric values all "3"? As if, I don't know, the closure vanished in a puff of illogic. `take-rw` doesn't cut it, either.

```
D:\>6e "my @bar = 'a', 'b', 'c'; sub foo( @b ) { my $bar = 0; eager gather loop { print "*"; take-rw ($bar, @b[$bar]); $bar++; last if $bar > 2; } }; .print for foo( @bar )"
***(3 a)(3 b)(3 c)
```

I can mitigate

```
D:\>6e "my @bar = 'a', 'b', 'c'; sub foo( @b ) { my $bar = 0; eager gather loop { print "*"; take-rw ($bar + 0, @b[$bar]); $bar++; last if $bar > 2; } }; .print for foo( @bar )"
***(0 a)(1 b)(2 c)
```

But why do I have to?

Edit: So, questions boils down to,

```
>6e "my $bar = 0; .say for gather { take ($bar,); $bar++; take ($bar,) }"
(0)
(1)

>6e "my $bar = 0; .say for eager gather { take ($bar,); $bar++; take ($bar,) }"
(1)
(1)
```

It is still unexplained, why there is a difference in behaviour in `eager` vs. `lazy` case.

Comment: The reason the lazy case works is because you don't notice that the old values changed out from under you, because they are already printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @BradGilbert:

> It is only about containers and values.
>
> The reason the lazy case works is because you don't notice that the old values changed out from under you, because they are already printed.

See Brad's and raiph's answers for further discussion.

Answer (score 6):

Holli has accepted the answer that quoted two of Brad's comments. I deliberately kept that one terse.

But you're reading this.<sup>1</sup> So I'll go in the opposite direction with this answer.

## `($bar,...)` is a list containing `$bar`, not `$bar`'s value

The behavior shown in the question really is all about containers vs values, and how list literals store containers, not their values<sup>1</sup>:

```
my $bar = 0;
my $list = ($bar,);
say $list[0];       # 0
$bar = 1;
say $list[0];       # 1
```

The laziness vs eager aspect is just things doing what they're all supposed to do. Emphasizing this first point may be enough to inspire you to focus on containers vs values. And maybe that'll lead you to quickly understand what went wrong in Holli's code. But maybe not.<sup>1</sup> So I'll continue.

## What happens in the lazy case?

A lazy list *waits until a value is demanded* before attempting to produce it. Then, it *just does the necessary work* and pauses, yielding control, until it's asked to produce another value at some later time.

In Holli's code the `for` loop demands values.

The first time around the `for` loop, it demands a value from the `lazy` expression. This turns around and demands a value from the `gather`'d expression. The latter then computes until the `take`, by which time it's created a list whose first element is the *container* `$bar`. This list is the result of the `take`.

Then the `.print` prints that first list. At the moment of printing, `$bar` still contains `0`. (The first increment of `$bar` hasn't yet happened.)

The second time around the `for` loop, the inner control structure enclosing the `take` (the `loop`) is re-entered. The first thing that happens is that `$bar` gets incremented for the first time. Then the loop exit condition is checked (and fails), so the second time around the loop starts. Another list is created. Then it's `take`d.

When the second list is printed, its first element, which is the `$bar` container, prints as `1`, not `0`, because at that point, having been incremented, `$bar` now contains `1`.

(If Holli had written code that held onto the first list, and printed that *first* list again *now*, after having just printed the second list, they'd have discovered that the *first* list *also* now printed with a `1`, no longer a `0`. Because all the `take`d lists have the *same* `$bar` container as their first element.)

And likewise the third list.

After the third list has been printed, the `for` loop demands a fourth go at the `gather`. This re-enters the `loop` at the statement after the `take` statement. `$bar` gets incremented for the third time, to `3`, and then the `last if $bar > 2;` condition triggers, exiting the loop (and thus the expression being `gather`'d and ultimately the whole `.print for ...` statement).

## What happens in the eager case?

*All* the `gather`ing is completed before *any* of the `print`ing.

At the end of this, the `for` construct has a sequence of three lists. It has not yet called any `.print` calls. The third time around the `loop` in the `gather` has left `$bar` containing `3`.

Next, `.print` is called on each of the three lists. `$bar` contains `3` so they all print with `3` as their first element.

## Solving the problem by switching to an array

I think the idiomatic way to deal with this would be to switch from a list literal to an array literal:

```
[$bar, @bar[$bar]]
# instead of
($bar, @bar[$bar])
```

This works because, unlike a *list* literal, an *array* literal treats an element that's a container as an *r-value*<sup>2</sup>, i.e. it *copies* the value **contained in** the container *out* of that container, rather than storing the container itself.

It just so happens that the value is copied *into another **new*** `Scalar` container. (That's because *all* elements of new non-native arrays are fresh `Scalar` containers; this one of the main things that makes an array different from a list.) But the effect in this context is the same as if the value were copied directly into the array because it no longer matters that the value contained in *`$bar`* is changing as things proceed.

The upshot is that the first element of the three arrays ends up containing, respectively, `0`, `1`, and `2`, the three values that were contained in `$bar` at the time each array was instantiated.

## Solving the problem by switching to an expression

As Holli noted, writing `$bar + 0` also worked.

In fact *any* expression will do, so long as it isn't just `$bar` on its own.

Of course, the expression needs to work, and return the right value. I think `$bar.self` should work and return the right value no matter what value `$bar` is bound to or assigned.

(Though it does read a little strangely; `$bar.self` is *not* `$bar` itself if `$bar` is bound to a `Scalar` container! Indeed, in an even more counter-intuitive twist, even `$bar.VAR`, which uses `.VAR`, a method which ["Returns the underlying `Scalar` object, if there is one."](https://docs.raku.org/language/mop#index-entry-syntax_VAR-VAR), still ends up being treated as an *r-value* instead!)

## Does the doc need updating?

The above is an entirely logical consequence of:

- What `Scalar`s are;
- What list literals do with `Scalar`s;
- What lazy vs eager processing means.

If the doc is weak, it's presumably in its explanation of one of the last two aspects. It looks like it's primarily the list literal aspect.

The [doc's **Syntax** page](https://docs.raku.org/language/syntax) has a section on various literals, including Array literals, but not list literals. The [doc's **Lists, sequences, and arrays**](https://docs.raku.org/language/list#Literal_lists) *does* have a **List literals** section (and not one on Arrays) but it doesn't mention what they do with `Scalar`s.

Presumably that warrants attention.

The **Lists, sequences, and arrays** page also has a [**Lazy lists**](https://docs.raku.org/language/list#Lazy_lists) section that could perhaps be updated.

Putting the above together it looks like the simplest doc fix might be to update the **Lists, sequences, and arrays** page.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> In my first couple versions of this answer ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59741483/1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59741483/2), I tried to get Holli to reflect on the impact of containers vs values. But that failed for them and maybe hasn't worked for you either. If you're not familiar with Raku's containers, consider reading:

- [Containers](https://docs.raku.org/language/containers), the official doc's "low-level explanation of Raku containers".
- [Containers in Perl 6](https://opensource.com/article/18/8/containers-perl-6), the third of Elizabeth Mattijsen's series of articles about Raku fundamentals for those familiar with Perl.

<sup>2</sup> Some of the details in [Wikipedia's discussion of "l-values and r-values"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)#lrvalue) don't fit Raku but the general principle is the same.

Comment: I am very aware of all of this. Read the question again. Here we have gather/take that produces different values depending on wether you iterate it lazily or eagerly. That's not normal. I tend to think Liz is right and this is a rakudo bug.

Comment: Not completely. Edit.

Comment: Laziness means storing lvalues doesn't make any difference; Eagerness means storing lvalues does make a difference

Ok. But why? Where in the docs does it say that?

Answer (score 2):

In Raku most values are immutable.

```raku
my $v := 2;
$v = 3;
```

```
Cannot assign to an immutable value
```

---

To make variables, you know actually variable, there is a thing called a *Scalar*.

By default `$` variables are actually bound to a new *Scalar* container.
(Which makes sense since they are called scalar variables.)

```raku
my $v;
say $v.VAR.^name; # «Scalar»

# this doesn't have a container:
my $b := 3;
say $v.VAR.^name; # «Int»
```

You can pass around this *Scalar* container.

```raku
my $v;

my $alias := $v;
$alias = 3;

say $v; # «3»
```

```raku
my $v;

sub foo ( $alias is rw ){ $alias = 3 }

foo($v);

say $v; # «3»
```

You can even pass it around in a list.

```raku
my $v;

my $list = ( $v, );

$list[0] = 3;

say $v; # «3»
```

This is the basis of the behaviour that you are seeing.

---

The thing is that you don't actually want to pass around the container, you want to pass around the value in the container.

So what you do is decontainerize it.

There are a few options for this.

```raku
$v.self
$v<>
$v[]
$v{}
```

Those last few only make sense on *Array* or *Hash* containers, but they also work on *Scalar* containers.

I would recommend using `$v.self` or `$v<>` for decontainerization.

(Technically `$v<>` is short for `$v{qw<>}` so it is for *Hash* containers, but there seems to be a consensus that `$v<>` can be used generally for this purpose.)

---

When you do `$v + 0` what you are doing is creating a new value object that is not in a *Scalar* container.

Since it is not in a container, the value itself gets passed instead of a container.

---

You don't notice this happening in the lazy case, but it is still happening.

It's just that you have printed the current value in the container before it gets changed out from underneath you.

```raku
my @bar = 'a', 'b', 'c';
sub foo( @b ) {
  my $bar = 0;
  gather loop {
    print "*";
    take ($bar, @b[$bar]);
    $bar++;
    last if $bar > 2;
  }
};

my \sequence = foo( @bar ).cache; # cache so we can iterate more than once

# there doesn't seem to be a problem the first time through
.print for sequence; # «*0 a*1 b*2 c»

# but on the second time through the problem becomes apparent
.print for sequence; # «3 a3 b3 c»

sequence[0][0] = 42;
.print for sequence; # «42 a42 b42 c»

say sequence[0][0].VAR.name; # «$bar»
# see, we actually have the Scalar container for `$bar`
```

You would also notice this if you used something like `.rotor` on the resulting sequence.

```raku
.put for foo( @bar ).rotor(2 => -1);

# **1 a 1 b
# *2 b 2 c
```

It's still just as lazy, but the sequence generator needs to create two values before you print it the first time. So you end up printing what is in `$bar` after the second `take`.
And in the second `put` you print what was is in it after the third `take`.
Specifically notice that the number associated with the `b` changed from a `1` to a `2`.
(I used `put` instead of `print` to split up the results. It would have the same behaviour with `print`.)

---

If you decontainerize, you get the value rather than the container.
So then it doesn't matter what happens to `$bar` in the meantime.

```raku
my @bar = 'a', 'b', 'c';
sub foo( @b ) {
  my $bar = 0;
  gather loop {
    print "*";
    take ($bar.self, @b[$bar]); # <------
    $bar++;
    last if $bar > 2;
  }
};

my \sequence = foo( @bar ).cache;

.print for sequence; # «*0 a*1 b*2 c»
.print for sequence; # «0 a1 b2 c»

# sequence[0][0] = 42; # Cannot modify an immutable List

# say sequence[0][0].VAR.name; # No such method 'name' for invocant of type 'Int'.


.put for foo( @bar ).rotor(2 => -1);

# **0 a 1 b
# *1 b 2 c
```

Comment: @Holli It is only about containers and values.