# List seems to be reused but bare value works fine

Tags: raku

This:

```
my %dict;
my $counter = 0;
for ^5 -> $digit {
        %dict{$digit} = ($counter,);
        $counter += 1;
}
say %dict;
```

gives me this:
`{0 => (5), 1 => (5), 2 => (5), 3 => (5), 4 => (5)}`,
but I'd expect this:
`{0 => (0), 1 => (1), 2 => (2), 3 => (3), 4 => (4)}`
Assigning a bare value, an array or hash works as I'd expect.

Comment: In summary `($counter,)` is a list whose first element is the *variable* `$counter`, not the value it contains. When that list is evaluated the variable's value is retrieved at that moment. The list is evaluated when `say %dict` is executed, at which time `$counter` is `5`.

Comment: This is a dupe of a small part of another SO, but the question and answer were waaay more complicated, so I'm delighted you've asked this simple version and will now go write a simple answer to this simple question (if someone else doesn't beat me to to it).

Comment: I've looked for but not found SOs I was thinking of. Here are links to a bit of verbiage in each of two SOs that are hopefully sufficiently related that they're useful: **1** [`($bar,...)` is a list containing `$bar`, not `$bar`'s value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59739980/strange-behaviour-of-eager-take#:~:text=(%24bar%2C...),bar%27s%20value) and **2** ["A `List` element is never rebindable, and is only assignable if it's bound to an *lvalue* at construction time."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580177/array-vs-list-data-type#:~:text=A%20List%20element,construction%20time.).

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. Are there any reasons as to why list literals work differently than array one's?

Comment: Sometimes it takes me ages to write an answer that I like enough. This is one such time. I plan to post an answer this weekend with a simple but rich explanation of the behavior, and of why the behavior and the surprise are both good things, covering a range of related aspects. I've drafted most of a nice answer but need to sleep on it.

Comment: "Are there any reasons as to why list literals work differently than array one's?" Absolutely. It's central to something I consider to be one of several unusual strengths of Raku, in how its design is grounded in how human brains/minds learn and teach each other. But I want to work toward an explanation of that which does the topic justice. I've only recently realized there's a ton of brain science that's done a 180 on hypotheses and theories about learning and teaching to catch up with Raku's approach, which essentially reflects and now vindicates how Larry Wall thinks about PL design.

Comment: As a quick workaround, you can  do `%dict{$digit} = ($counter++,);`.  The `$counter++` will place the **value** of the counter prior to incrementing in the list.  And thus will kill two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `($counter,)` is lazy (probably??). It's a list, you'll observe the same issue when you do `List.new($counter)`. So the creation isn't truly evaluated until you print the map. If you change to a non lazy data structure ie. an Array, using `[$counter,]` or `Array.new($counter)`. It should work as you expect.

```
my %dict;
my $counter = 0;
for ^5 -> $digit {
        %dict{$digit} = [$counter,];
        $counter += 1;
}
say %dict;
```

Prints:

```
{0 => [0], 1 => [1], 2 => [2], 3 => [3], 4 => [4]}
```